Is there any way to get Headers from HttpResponse in HttpClient5?
In Apache HTTP Components 4, I could get Header[] from HttpResponse by using the method getAllHeaders(), cause this method extends from class HttpMessage. However, after upgrading my dependency to 5.x, I found that this method has been removed from class HttpResponse. The only solution I found is to change HttpResponse to CloseableHttpResponse then use method getHeaders(). Is this the correct approach?
Is there any way to get Headers from HttpResponse in HttpClient5?

Both HttpRequest and HttpResponse extend a common base interface MessageHeaders. There is #getHeaders method that returns an array of all headers contained in the message.
However I would strongly recommend using #headerIterator as it is likely to be more memory efficient, especially for larger messages.

u r right, thanks a lot

i would use HttpClientUtils.closeQuietly(httpResponse); to close response in the past, but now HttpClientUtils this class has been removed, what should i do nowdays?

Use Closer#closeQuietly
